# Can't change the applied theme in 2.2.4 from admin

Tags: magento2.2.4

Here is a known bug in 2.2.4 version.

When you try to apply theme from backend content -> Design -> Configuration:

Appears the error: "Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set"

It will be fix in 2.2.5 version by magento guys.

Meanwhile here the solution:

You can refer this link from github they given solution to solve for 2.2.4 version.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968#event-1630525002

Or change the core files from here they commited on github:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0ae1230c4bbe985f66929ed234835137e64664c9
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/3df51d4c294dda946d78ba25b9aef693cb813a0a
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0dec988872e175e568c2bf4bb29548ab7a4698e5
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d92b679e48da825813bfaff51e631236a2bbc73a

This will fix the issue.